# I need an easiest way to alter the contents of a file using a python script

Tags: python-3.x, file

I have a python file "main.py" which has some code inside it I need a python simple function to find and replace a certain line of code in it.
**Example: main.py contains**

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def index_user(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if validate_checks(instance):
        index_model(instance)
```

I need a function to change the above code into

```
# @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def index_user(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if validate_checks(instance):
        index_model(instance)
```

Comment: Just read the file line-by-line and search for the text you want to replace. Although, you might have to create a copy of existing file to make your changes.

Comment: I need to update the existing file without creating another one.

Comment: This is usually a task for an IDE. Are you sure you need to do this manually? What is your criteria for identifying a file, and how do you want to change it? Is it always for an exact match and appending ``# ``?

Comment: It is always for an exact match and appending #. I have the file in a project. I just need to update the file with these changes. I want to add a # and remove it with the help of a function whenever i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the entire file into memory, make the changes you want, then write those changes to the same file.

So, a basic piece of code that does what you want:

```py
def replace_and_write(fn: str, exact_match: str, replacement: str) -> None:
    with open(fn, "r") as f_in:
        contents = f_in.read()

    with open(fn, "w") as f_out:
        f_out.write(contents.replace(exact_match, replacement))

replace_and_write("test.txt", "foo", "Hello, World!")
```

Running this on a file that used to look like:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

Will change it to:

```
Hello, World!
bar
baz
```